# How do I make Wordpress to display apple emoji?

Tags: emoji

Wordpress displays emoji unicode symbols using an icon set like this one http://emojione.com/#gallery but I don't want this version. Emoji looks so different in Wordpress. Is it possible to use another icon pack that looks more native, like the the emojipedia link:
https://emojipedia.org/people/

Comment: i guess it's based on the system. i found more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875299/how-to-use-an-emoji-font-on-a-website

Answer (score 1):

Copying [my answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ios-emoji/#post-10787822) from the .org forums:

> You can’t force WordPress to use iOS emoji for anyone but iOS (or Mac)
>   users.
>
> Emoji are just characters, like any other letter, and how they’re
>   displayed is determined by the operating system. Each operating system
>   has its own graphics for the emoji, and they will be displayed using
>   these.
>
> However, to enable emoji in browsers and operating systems that don’t
>   support them WordPress uses a script to convert emoji to a
>   backwards-compatible format, and these backwards-compatible emoji are
>   [Twemoji](https://twemoji.twitter.com/), Twitter’s emoji designs. It uses these because they’re open
>   source, which is a requirement for WordPress.
>
> You can disable these backwards-compatibility emoji with a plugin like
>   [Disable Emojis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/). When using this plugin emoji will only appear in
>   compatible browsers (most of them these days), but they will appear in
>   the original style of the user’s operating system. So iOS users will
>   see the iOS designs, but Android users will see their device
>   manufacturer’s designs.
>
> It’s not possible to force everyone to use Apple’s designs for emoji,
>   because these are copyrighted and tightly controlled by Apple.